# Cannot be resolving in JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new in java and found this after importing project

How can i solve it?

[image]

Comment: Those are not errors. Those are classes.

Comment: so what's the solution to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Window` > `Show View` > `Other...`. Choose `General` > `Problems` or search for `Problems` and add it. Look for the exact reason for red marks on your packages.

**Update**

Looks like your source folder is misplaced. Follow the steps below:

1. Right click on the project, go to `Properties`
2. Choose `Java Build Path` on the left pane.
3. Click on `<Project_name>/src` and click `Remove`
4. Click on `Add Folder`, choose check boxes (if found) `java` & `resources` under the trees `src`>`main` and `src`>`test`
5. Click `OK` and then `OK` on Properties dialog.

### Image reference:

[image]

Comment: Thank for helping , i titled my post with cannot be resolving and there are 100 errors some of them cannot be resolved as a type , Hence "i ran this project before successfully " and now errors again appears , i don't know what's the problem

Comment: When it says cannot be resolved type, first thing we need to do is add the dependency. It could be by `jar` or `maven` or some other way. You can search for the non found item, see the way to resolve dependency.

Comment: thanks i'm beginner so i'm sorry for my question how can i get resolving of any item ?

Comment: Please comment one item that shows cannot be found.

Comment: Double click on that item, it should be a `Java` file. Go to the top of that file, look at `import` where it shows in red. Comment those items marked in red.

Comment: i've question, i imported the project as java but it has pom.xml so i converted it to maven and when i imported it like what can you see in screenshot in the package explorer main.java.class_name and so on why class _name didn't appear without main.java !

Comment: Thanks for your patience , i tried your solution but problem still

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89443/discussion-between-james-jithin-and-user3188912).

Comment: it's less thing i can do for your help